# How to set an exact search box in tablepress plug-in

Tags: plugins, search, table, csv

I installed TablePress and set a table that contains 20 rows and 3 columns.
I want to let people to search an unique digit number from a column and
show the result as value of the same row or three columns, but not other rows.

The filter of the tablepress give me only a part search box, that allow me to see other rows while I type.

How can I strict it to a whole word search. The exact match search.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably ask TablePress support directly sorry - you're more likely to find someone who knows that plugin well there.